# JQueryUI datepicker() initializer not working from events other than onload

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

while binding the datepicker Widget works when doing it on page onload event, it isn't working from the onclick event.

Works good:

```
$()
{
   $('#StartDate').datepicker();    
};
```

Not working - throws exception (Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function) when i click on the textbox:

```
$("#StartDate").click(function (e)
{
    $('#StartDate').datepicker();    
});
```

I'm using the last versions of JQuery and JQueryUI.

Comment: you have to rebind it.

Comment: Whats the exception?

Comment: what is '#StartDate' ? is it a div ? Input box ? button ?

Comment: your code is totally fine and doing what it should do (click on input field inits the datepicker - and opens on the second click)... no errors on a test fiddle. So your issue might be how you include your scripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do like

```
$("#StartDate").click(function (e)
{
   //this will rebind datepicker
   $(this).removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker();
});
```

Comment: Now i am getting: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).removeClass(...).removeAttr(...).datepicker is not a function

Comment: can you browser datepicker jQuery with inspect?

Comment: i think problem with datepicker js.

Comment: Didn't get your hint. Do you want me to inspect the INPUT element? what to share with you?

Comment: If the problem is with datepicker.js so how the 
$()
{
   $('#StartDate').datepicker();    
};

work ok?

could you please give it a try? :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97983/discussion-between-parth-trivedi-and-omtechguy).

Comment: problem with jquery added twice.

Answer (score 0):

This may cause by your scripts referencing, Make sure all scripts referencing are at the beginning of your razor view. So scripts can be loaded properly:

On top of your View, Try add, make it correspond with your scripts version:

```
<link href="~/Content/themes/base/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js"></script>
```

Then Add at the buttom:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
            $("#StartDate").datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',

            }).val()
        });
</script>
```

Comment: he even didn't mentioned that he's using .net MVC

Comment: Yeah hopefully it will help.

Comment: I am using MVC - jquery added twice :(

Comment: Yours or mine? Cz that might also cause the problem from loading

Comment: The problem was at my side of course, i added the jquery twice by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, you basically want to trigger datepicker on click of textbox (#StartDate), try this,

```
$("#StartDate").datepicker({
            showOn: "button"

        });
```

You will need to add showon property to "button" for each element.